# Boxplot-like graph using two vectors to split into single group

Tags: r

I have a dataset looking like so:

```
   obs   Mod    UTMx   UTMy
1  0.48  0.51   560517 7626248
2  0.39  0.51   560517 7626248
3  0.48  0.51   560517 7626248
4  0.54  0.51   560517 7626248
5  0.46  0.48   560567 7626248
6  0.48  0.42   560617 7626448
7  0.48  0.42   560617 7626448
8  0.53  0.42   560617 7626448
9  0.54  0.52   560667 7626698
10 0.40  0.52   560667 7626698
```

What I would like to do is to plot the range of values in `obs` that have the same `UTMx` and `UTMy`, a bit like in a boxplot. So for example if we were to have a boxplot, rows 1 to 4 have the same UTMx and UTMy so box 1 would use the `obs` values from these four rows. Then rows 6 to 8 for box 2, and rows 9 and 10 for box 3. I do have the occasional data like in row 5 where there is no duplicate for UTMx and UTMy so one point isn't enough for a box, which is why I wasn't necessarily suggesting a boxplot.

Finally, I will also need to plot `Mod` in the same plot e.g. the single value in `Mod[1:4]` should be on top of box1 as I am comparing observations to model output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_labels <- df %>% 
    group_by(UTMx, UTMy) %>% 
    summarize_all(max)


ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction(UTMx, UTMy), y = obs)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_text(data = df_labels, aes(label = Mod), nudge_y = .01)
```

[image]

Data:

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'obs   Mod    UTMx   UTMy
1  0.48  0.51   560517 7626248
2  0.39  0.51   560517 7626248
3  0.48  0.51   560517 7626248
4  0.54  0.51   560517 7626248
5  0.46  0.48   560567 7626248
6  0.48  0.42   560617 7626448
7  0.48  0.42   560617 7626448
8  0.53  0.42   560617 7626448
9  0.54  0.52   560667 7626698
10 0.40  0.52   560667 7626698', header = T)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!